# Oracle composite index

Tags: oracle, plsql

If I have a table with columns a,b,c,d and and pk b-tree index on (a,b,c) in that order. I want to query like so:
(1)

```
select b, d from table 
where a = :p1
  and c = :p2
```

I.e. missing a where clause on the b column for perfect leveraging the index. Now the b column can only have one of a few possible values (20 unique) but c (and a) can have a lot (100 000's). I figured it would be more efficient to rewrite the query to:

(2)

```
select /*+USE_NL(table)*/ b, d from table 
where a = :p1
  and b IN (<allPossibleValues>)
  and c = :p2
```

but I haven't been able to find any oracle documentation that explains how the range scan in (1) works when a non-leading column is missing from the composite index. All the sources seem to only cover the case where the leading column is missing. Those sources suggest using a skip scan like so:

(3)

```
select /*+INDEX_SS(table <theIndex>)*/ b, d from table 
where a = :p1
  and c = :p2
```

Would that work when the missing column is not the leading one but the second one (b). As I said all the sources I've found explaining skip scan have the leading column missing. Would query (2) and/or (3) be better than query (1).

Answer (score 0):

Before starting premature optimization, check the explain plan and the performance of your original query in your production environment.

The Oracle query optimizer is quite good at choosing the correct plan. Depending on the size of your table it will probably choose either full index scan (I guess the table has way to many rows for this to happen), or index range scan.

If Oracle fails to choose a plan with good performance, then you can start optimizing.

Comment: Oracle chooses an index range scan and I'm having performance problems with the query. I'm now wondering if query (2) or (3) could improve this. I have run local tests that suggest that they would but I would like to get this confirmed and understand why.

Comment: How does the plan change when you switch to query 2 and query 3?

Comment: You can always speed it up by adding an index for `a,c,d`. Having all fields you access in the index can really speed up performance if your query returns many rows.

Comment: In (2) oracle does a nested loop over the possible values of b into table. In (3) it uses a skip scan which logically should be similar to (2). I don't want to add a new index.

Comment: If you have few rows in the result, nested loops may give the best result. If you have many, a skip scan is probably faster. The actual performance must be measured in your production system, of course. The reason I'm nagging about measuring in production is because execution plan and relative performance may differ if the dev/test environment has other hardware specifications or less data.

If 2 and 3 have similar performance I would choose 3, because then I wouldn't need to change the SQL if I add another value for B.